# How is this type of input label accomplished?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how these HTML inputs are achieved:

[image]

Google uses these inputs where the placeholder transitions up into the corner and becomes the label once the input is clicked. I thought they were somehow using the `<fieldset>` with the `<legend>` to accomplish this, but inspecting the code shows they are using an input with a div.. Is there a native way to do this I haven't heard of, or does anyone know how this is accomplished?

[example link](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with just html+css using conditional selectors. Example fiddle:

```css
main {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid lightgray 1px;
  padding: 16px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

input + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  color: gray;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:focus + label {
  transform: scale(0.75) translate(-24px, -40px);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input name="foo" />
  <label for="foo">Click the Input</label>
</main>
```